# Why is this definition of inner product violating the axioms?

Tags: inner-products

for all real polynomials , I defined inner product of two polys to be  (f.g)=f(1)g(1).

It seems to me that it does not violate any of axioms.

If there is , can you tell me for what axioms are violated?

Answer (score 2):

For example, the polynomial defined by $f(x)=x-1$ is not the zero polynomial, yet it has $f\cdot f=0$.

Comment: wait, I know that (f.f)>0 if f is not equal to 0. but here, are you saying that f(x) is not 0 ? not f(1) is not 0?

Comment: So, what is not equal to 0? f(1) or f(x) ? that was why I was confused. I thought that (f.f)>0 if f(1) is not 0

Comment: The elements of your vector space are polynomials: $f=0$ means $f(x)=0$ **for all $x$ values**, not just $f(1)=0$.  Note that $f(1)$ is not a polynomial, it is just a number.